# how to access mainwindow from another class?

Tags: c#, wpf

I as the title says. I want to be able to change the GUI mainwindow from other classes. When i have all methods in the mainwindow class everything workes fine. But when i use another class in same namespace it doesn't work. My code compiles but when i click on button nothing happens.

```
class w_Kcal
{
    MainWindow mw;

    public w_Kcal(MainWindow mw)
    {
        this.mw = mw;
        mw.maintenanceButton.Click += MaintenanceButton_Click;
    }

    public void MaintenanceButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        mw.maintenanceBox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        mw.maintenanceOKBtn.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
}
```

Mainwindow:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question does not make sense. What do you mean? What button? Your button's just changing the visibility of two controls on MainWindow.

Comment: Note, this is not the right way to do MVVM, you should not be having references to your window in your view model. That event should go in the codebehind of the MainWindow class.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you do not instantiate `w_Kcal` anywhere. Create this class in main window code and it should work:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private w_Kcal helper;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        helper = new w_Kcal(this);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps